# Hover over div changes another div heading

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, jquery-hover

I will try to explain this the best I can. 
I have 5 boxes and want 1 box to have a different heading color. When I hover over the other 4 boxes I want the active box heading to change, resulting in the new heading to be a different color. Mouse off and the heading will stay that color.

I set it up so when you hover over an image the paragraph text changes according to the image. I have placeholder text that disappears when a hover action takes place.

Everything I tried doesn't work but I know there's an answer. Thank you so much!

Here's my code:

```
<div class="process">     
            <div class="step box-1">
                <img src="img/seed.jpg" rel="first-step">
                <h3>SEED</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step box-2">
                <img src="img/seedling.jpg" rel="second-step">
                <h3>CULTIVATE</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step box-3">
                <img src="img/drop" rel="third-step">
                <h3>DISTILL</h3>
            </div>
<h4 class="steps first-step"> 
            Powerful, effective essential oils come from seeds and plants that are verified for their essential oil potential by Young Living experts, partnering with university experts. 
            </h4>
            <h4 class="steps second-step">
            Young Living farms, located around the globe, are dedicated to perfecting the best growing and harvesting methods. Our experts also travel the world visiting our co-op farms to verify that their growing and cultivating processes match our high standards. These operations provide an ongoing source for essential oils that meet Young Living's demanding quality standards. 
            </h4>
            <h4 class="steps third-step">
            Combining ancient and modern techniques, Young Living is recognized as an innovator in essential oil distillation. We use a gentle, proprietary technique for steam extracting the most effective essential oils, as well as using cold pressing and resin tapping methods for select oils. 
            </h4> 
            <div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $placeholder = $('.placeholder');
$('.step> img').hover(function() {
var $rel = $(this).attr('rel');
$placeholder.hide();
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
var $captions = $('.steps');
$captions.hide();
$('.step> img').hover(function() {
var $rel = $(this).attr('rel');
$captions.hide();
$('.steps.'+ $rel +'').show();
});
});
```

Comment: which box should have different color? can you give an example as well?

Comment: so only the selected header should be different color?

Comment: When the user visits the page, "Seed" should be a different color with its placeholder text. When you hover over the other images, the text changes and the heading color should change too. I know how to do a simple hover but I need the "Seed" color to go back to the original color.

Comment: when user selects an item the style of that item should change, while others maintain the default style. This repeats for each selected item?

Comment: Yes and always having an item selected after hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $placeholder = $('.placeholder');
    var $captions = $('.steps');
    $captions.hide();
    $('.step> img').hover(function() {
        var $rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $captions.hide();
        $placeholder.hide();
        $('.step h3').css('color', 'black');
        $(this).siblings('h3').css('color', 'red');
        $('.steps.'+ $rel +'').show();
    });
});
```

First yo set all `.step h3` to color **black**. Then set the active `h3` to **red**.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I wouldn't of figured out the sibling selectors.